# how to change the html of elementor page using wp_posts? is it even possible?

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I changed the HTML structure of Elementor through the wp_posts table in the database, but there were no changes happening on the page. So, I deleted the meta value from the wp_postmeta table. Now I can see the changes, but the CSS is gone. How can I solve this problem? I want the changes to take place on the page without losing the CSS.

Comment: O have absolutely no idea what you are asking. Could you explain how you did all this? And why? Changing the elementor structure at database level is a very bad idea. It will get overridden whenever you save the page/post in the backend.